# Let $f:M\to N$ be continuous, then $f(U)\subset V$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $f:M\to N$ be continuous, with $M$ and $N$ metric spaces. Given an arbitrary subset $X \subset M$ and an open set $V \subset N$, with $f(X) \subset V$, prove that there exists an open subset $U$, with $X\subset U$ in $M$ and $f(U)\subset V$.

My approach: Let $f:M\to N$ continuous, then the inverse image of an open set $V\subset N$, i.e. $f^{-1}(V)$, is an open subset in $M$, namely X. Therefore X is open in $M$. Now, how $X\subset U$ implies $f(U)\subset V$, I think maybe works that, all open sets is as the union of open set. Any hint pls!

Comment: What assumptions on $U$ are there?  Does $U$ need to be open?  How about non-empty?

Comment: Also, if $f(X) \subseteq V$ does not imply $f^{-1}(V) = X$.  Do you understand why?

Comment: The problem still seems to be misstated. If $\subset$ means "subset" then $U=X$ works. If it means proper subset, then the conclusion doesn't follow.

Comment: you probably also want $U$ to be open, I guess.

Comment: @Giovanni Yes, that exactly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a standard application of an equivalent formulation of continuity:

- $f$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if for every $V$ open neighborhood of $f(x)$ there is an open neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ such that $f(U_x) \subset V$. ([This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Neighborhood_definition) is a reference to this fact.)

Now all you have to do is to consider $U = \bigcup_{x \in X}U_x.$

$U$ defined in this way is open being the union of open sets, it contains $X$, and its image under $f$ is contained in $V$ since $$f(\bigcup_{x \in X}U_x) \subset \bigcup_{x \in X}f(U_x) \subset \bigcup_{x \in X}V = V.$$